# Firebase Stream function not working correctly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-esp8266

I am working with ESP8266 and [Firebase-Arduino](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino) library. I am trying to use the *stream* function but I am facing a problem with `Firebase.available()`.

I know that `Firebase.available()` returns a `true` value whenever a change occurs on the real time database. But in my case it returns a `true` value every *30 seconds* irrespective of the change has taken place or not.

- Is this normal?
- If not then how to fix it?

I am using the example [code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/blob/master/examples/FirebaseStream_ESP8266/FirebaseStream_ESP8266.ino) provided for *FirebaseStream*.